# Card found in arena showing not found

Tags: clash-royale

I unlocked a few legendary cards, then I played a game or two with the cards I had just unlocked in arenas 6, 7, and 8. After a while, I noticed my cards were gone and there were no legendary cards available.

Why did this happen?

Comment: How did you unlock your cards ? Regular chest (main screen), Shop, gems chest ?

Comment: It was through Chests.

Comment: This is a pretty serious issue, and it's not likely due to lag. Have you tried to contact Supercell?

Answer (score 2):

Many scenarios could have happened here:

**Your game crashed**

If a game crashes, the previously stored data could be lost. If only your recent data was deleted, unfortunately, your data, cards, and arena are unrestorable.

I know this can happen from personal experience with games like this and others as well.

**Unlinked account**

Your account could have been unlinked from your phone, and therefore Clash Royale. This can happen if there is an insecure or slow internet connection, and you then must relink your account and select "Yes" when prompted to restore data.

**Purchases restored**

If you bought your cards in the shop, with real money, your account might have restored purchases and undone every purchase on Clash Royale. This could happen by accident, or by a supervisor of your account (parent or guardian). You will have to re-purchase at that point and hope to be as lucky as you were when you got your legendaries.

**Server failure**

If everything above does not apply, the only other option is that a server owned by Supercell lost your data. If this is true, [contact Supercell](http://supercell.com/en/contact-us/) as soon as possible so you will be able to recover your data.

**Help me help you**

It would be much easier if you were to tell me your type of phone (iOS or Android), show screenshots of the game and your missing cards, and tell me if you have purchased any in-game items on Clash Royale in order to narrow down the scenarios.

Remember to check if you are logged-in, if your purchases are restored, if your game has crashed recently, or other unusual behavior, and comment it to make it easier for me to find you your solution.

Comment: Hi, Actually I never purchased from google, I got the cards on reaching higher arena via chests. I was a newbie and was not having much idea of legendary might be important like this. Suddenly I realised I am having some missing card. Firstly I just thought these have been removed due to loss of the trophies.

Comment: @AshishRatan See the first part of my answer you must have a faulty internet connection or a sudden crash.

Comment: @AshishRatan I've also updated my answer with another possibility that could match your case.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that your game did not save correctly, which can be caused by a game crash or poor internet. Cards, on their own, do not "disappear" unless they are upgraded or donated to someone else.

Source: Personal experience
I attempted to purchase a Clone for 1000 Gold, which showed up in my list of cards. However, due to poor internet, the game did not save, and 30 minutes later, my clone disappeared.